# vagrant domain ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: apache, vagrant, local, hostname

I am new here so let me know if i do something wrong :-)

I ran in a bit of trouble trying out Vagrant!
I installed a Vagrant Ubuntu:xenial64 box running apache2 and php 7.1 on it, it all runs smooth I can access it with ssh also in the browser by using the local ip (10.10.10.10) but I also connected a local domain ( **test-site.dev** ) here I am getting a "*ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED*" error. I already try'd many fixed from many topic on the internet but none is working.

- forwarded_port ( 80 > 8080 )
- Added **test-site.dev** to /etc/host on Vagrant box
- Added **test-site.dev** to windows host file
- Looked at the firewall on the box ( disabled )
- Made site in sites-available with the serverName and alias
- Try'd other browsers

I am running all of this on a windows 10 machine. Does anyone has more tips for this problem?

**EDIT:**
Problem was resolved, the problem was the domain extension. .dev seems to be forced with a internal 307 redirect to https. This is wat broke it for me.

Comment: So from the same machine: http://10.10.10.10/ works but http://test-site.dev/ does not work? Have you verified that your syntax for /etc/hosts is correct? Do you have some resolver configuration that is skipping all /etc/hosts entries?

Comment: Hi, double checked the host file, made a typo there 127.0.1.1 instead of 127.0.0.1 but didn't fixed the problem. Also forgot to activate the site so it wasn't in sites-enabled. But it also didn't fix my problem. Dont know what you mean by resolver configuration. Hope somebody has another solution that i didn't think of.

Comment: First off, is it 127.0.0.1 or 10.10.10.10? Those are much different addresses. Secondly: The resolver is the thing that turns a domain name into an address. On traditional unix, `/etc/nsswitch.conf` controls the order that things get consulted. Sometimes "files" is not part of the order, in that case `/etc/hosts` does not get used. To test, create an obvious bogus entry and see if "ping" resolves it. Eg: `8.8.8.8 bozo.dns` and `ping bozo.dns`

Comment: Sorry my mistake, 127.0.0.1 is the Vagrant machine, 10.10.10.10 is its local IP what I can call from windows. So I added the bogus entry on the vagrant machine /etc/hosts. After I saved that I pinged it and its pointing to 8.8.8.8 like it should. Windows hostfile also points to the right direction when I ping test-site.dev it points to 10.10.10.10 ( vagrant machine ). It realy looks like something on the vagrant machine is blocking the hostnames to access.

Comment: So it could be the vagrant blocking, but I'm doubtful of that. It occurs to me that .dev is a valid top level domain. Maybe trying a different one that doesn't actually exist?

Comment: Oké! I found the problem by exident. I was looking at a video tutorial about a pre configured vagrant box and the guy told that he didn't use a .dev address because browsers didn't like that and forced those addresses to https. Well i changed my vhost to dev.domain.nl and poof it worked. So the .dev extension was the problem! Thanks for the support! @CupcakeProtocol